# SQL view to select the last 3 months of payroll data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a view that I want to use to generate a payroll report. 
I want it such that it selects/gets the last 3 months of monthly processed data. 
E.g. If today is 15th May 2012 and payroll for May has not been done, I want to get the results for April, March and February only.

My query:

```
SELECT  dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year, dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID, SUM(dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Amount) AS PAYE, 
              dbo.OADM.CompnyName, dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr, dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum, dbo.OHEM.lastName + ', ' + ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.middleName, '') 
              + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.firstName, '') AS EmployeeName, dbo.OHEM.govID, dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Process_month
FROM     dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA] INNER JOIN
               dbo.OHEM ON dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID = dbo.OHEM.empID CROSS JOIN
               dbo.OADM
WHERE   (dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_PD_code = 'SYS033')
GROUP BY dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Tax_year, dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Employee_ID, dbo.OADM.CompnyName, dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr, dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum, 
                      dbo.OHEM.lastName, dbo.OHEM.firstName, dbo.OHEM.middleName, dbo.OHEM.govID, dbo.[@EIM_PROCESS_DATA].U_Process_month
```

The field U_Process_Month stores the name of the months of the year (varchar). Any help?

Comment: Have you tried ordering them by month descending and selecting the `top 3` ?

Comment: Do never, *never*, **never** store dates in the form of a string. **Always** use a datetime. If you need to display them, you can always convert the datetime to a string representation, but doing it the other way round is insecure, has a low performance and is just a big pain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option if you want to turn a month name into a datetime:

```
declare @Month varchar(10) = 'DEC'
declare @Year varchar(4) = '2012'

SELECT CAST(@Month ' ' + @Year AS DATETIME) AS KeyDate
```

Replace the @Month and @Year variables with your field names, and you have the first step ;-)

For selecting only the last three months, try the `HAVING` clause, together with a variable `@MaxKeydate` that indicates the last processed month:

```
SELECT (...) FROM bla
HAVING KeyDate > DATEADD(month, -3, @MaxKeyDate)
```

You need to see yourself, if you can determine the value for `@MaxKeyDate` with a simple

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(@Month ' ' + @Year AS DATETIME)) FROM bla
```

or if it is more complicated.